# What does cpython do to help detect object cycles(reference counting)?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, reference-counting, cpython, proof

From what I've read about cpython it seems like it does reference counting + something extra to detect/free objects pointing to each other.(Correct me if I'm wrong). Could someone explain the something extra? Also does this guarantee* no cycle leaking? If not is there any research into an algorithm proven to add to reference counting to make it never leak*? Would this be just running a non reference counting tracing gc every so often?

*discounting bugs and problems with modules using foreign function interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the documentation for [`gc.garbage`](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.garbage), there is no guarantee that no leaks occur; specifically, cyclic objects with `__del__` methods are not collected by default. For such objects, the cyclic links have to be manually broken to enable further GC.

From what I understand by browsing the [CPython sourcecode](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/gcmodule.c?revision=81029&view=markup), the interpreter keeps references to all objects under its control. The "extra" garbage collector runs a mark-and-sweep-like algorithm through the heap, remembers for each object if it is reachable from the "outside" and, if not, deletes it. (The GC is [generational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Generational_GC_.28aka_Ephemeral_GC.29), but it may be run explicitly from the `gc` module with a `generation` argument.)

The only efficient algorithm that I could think of that satisfies your criteria would indeed be a "full" GC algorithm to augment reference counting and this is what seems to be implemented in Python. I'm not an expert in these matters though.